# Why is the data from my html form not submitting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing asp.net mvc application.  I have a section on the form where I add some text boxes dynamically when the user clicks a "Add New Part" button.  The problem is when I submit the form I don't get the data from the fields I added dynamically.  I am passing the FormCollection to my controller and stepping through the code in the debugger and those fields are not there.  If I look at them in firebug I see them just fine.  Any ideas?

Here is the javascript for adding the text fields to the page:

```
function moreFields() {
        var newFields = document.getElementById('readrootpu').cloneNode(true);
        newFields.id = '';
        newFields.style.display = 'block';
        var newField = newFields.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
            var theName = newField[i].name
            if (theName)
                newField[i].name = theName;
        }
        var insertHere = document.getElementById('newpartusageitems');
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields, insertHere);
    }
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="readrootpu" class="usedparts" style="display: none">
    <% var fieldPrefix = "PartUsage[]."; %>
    Part ID:
    <%= Html.TextBox(fieldPrefix + "ID", "")%>
    Serial Number:
    <%= Html.TextBox(fieldPrefix + "Serial", "")%>
    Quantity:
    <%= Html.TextBox(fieldPrefix + "Quantity", "") %>
    <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" />
</div>
```

When I inspect the html with firebug it looks fine to me:

```
Part ID: <input type="text" name="PartUsage[].ID" id="PartUsage[]_ID" value="" />
Serial Number: <input type="text" name="PartUsage[].Serial" id="PartUsage[]_Serial" value="" />
Quantity: <input type="text" name="PartUsage[].Quantity" id="PartUsage[]_Quantity" value="" />
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 1):

Verify with Firebug that all the post data is being sent from the page via the "Net" tab.

Also, i agree with Kobi: you need to increment the ID's on the cloned elements so they are unique.

I would suggest you look into jQuery for dynamically creating html elements. I have only just started learning jQuery and its very easy.
The following code demonstrates a simple file upload form that allows the user can add more input elements dynamically. Each time the jQuery adds a new input element, i append a chr to the id attribute so they are all unique. Hopefully this helps you:

The script block for the jQuery.. notice the last part is for the ajax animation. The actual copying code is only those 4 lines from $("#moreFiles").click

> ```
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>         var counter = "oneFile";
>         $(document).ready(function() {
>             $("#moreFiles").click(function() {
>                 var newCounter=counter+"1";
>                 $("p#"+counter).after("<p id='"+newCounter+"'><input type='file' name='"+newCounter+"' id='"+newCounter+"' size='60' /></p>");
>                 counter=newCounter;
>             });
>             $("#submitUpload").click(function() {
>                 $("#submitUpload").val("Uploading...");
>                 $("img.uploadingGif").show(); 
>             });
>         });
>     </script>
> ```

..and the aspnet markup:

```
    <% string postUrl = Model.PostUrl + (Model.ModelID > 0 ? "/" + Model.ModelID.ToString() : ""); %>
    <form id="uploadForm" class="uploadForm" action="<% =postUrl %>" 
        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Select file(s) for upload (size must not exceed 
            <% =Html.Encode(ServiceConstants.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE_INBYTES) %> bytes):</label>  
        <p id="oneFile"><input type="file" name="oneFile" id="oneFile" size="60" /></p>
        <% if(Model.MultipleFiles) { %>
            <p><a id="moreFiles" href="#">add more files</a></p>
            <input id="MultipleFiles" type="hidden" name="MultipleFiles" value="true" />
        <% } %>
        <p><%--<input id="submitUpload" type="submit" value="Upload" />--%>
        <% =Html.InputSubmit("Upload","submitUpload") %>
            <% =Html.LoadingImage("uploadingGif") %>
    </form>
```

..this all only boils down to a few lines of html and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple values on fields with same names, you should be able to see them on the server side using `Request.Form.GetValues("key")`.

You should note that when you clone the nodes, you create copies with the same IDs, which is considered invalid.
Also, you have a `for` loop there, and I don't quite get what it does (reads the node's name and sets it back - what is the reason for doing that? Should that be `var theName = newField`**s**`[i].name` ?)

Answer (score 0):

I was working with plain HTML when my form worked fine if all the fields were left blank, but it would not submit if I filled out the form.

Later I realized that it was because of a text-field entry 'Email' in which I was entering an email-address containing the character '@'. When I removed the '@', the form started submitting again.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot just aribtrarily add text boxes client-side without having the corresponding server-side controls ready to read the data from the postback. However, you should be able to read the raw data from HttpRequest.Form.

update: oops! it's MVC. I didn't read^H^H^H^H see that. never mind.

-Oisin

Comment: I am looking at HttpRequest.Form but the fields that are added on the client side are not being sent back to the server.

Comment: @x0n: it's not asp.net webforms, it's asp.net mvc. You *can* post anything